# How to configure to auto detect proxy?

Tags: networking, configuration, proxy

In the `Windows` have an option to check to detect automatically proxy.
[image: Windows proxy configuration]

But when I'm setting the Ubuntu to detect proxy automatically, it's requesting me about some URL:[image: Ubuntu proxy configuration]

But I have not idea what the URL I need put in.

How can I configure my Ubuntu to detect proxy automatically?

Comment: I think [this page on setting up proxy auto config on Ubuntu Desktop](http://xmodulo.com/how-to-set-up-proxy-auto-config-on-ubuntu-desktop.html) explains what you need to do fairly clearly.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did almost the same way, but your suggestion was helpful for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved the problem based in [this post](http://xmodulo.com/how-to-set-up-proxy-auto-config-on-ubuntu-desktop.html), but I downloaded the proxy configuration file.

I used a Windows, which connection is working, then I access the URL `http://wpad/wpad.dat` to download the config file.

Then I logged my Linux, and used the file as proxy auto detect config.

[image: Linux proxy configuration]

Comment: The link you used is now dead, [archived here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170421054858/http://xmodulo.com/how-to-set-up-proxy-auto-config-on-ubuntu-desktop.html), could you incorporate more information from that page into your answer?