# How to auto configure proxy on ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: networking, 18.04, proxy

On my work place I am behind a proxy, and I have set it manually as shown in the image below:

[image: proxy settings]

I use the same laptop at home as well, where I don't need proxy configuration.

**Problem:**

Everyday I need to set the proxy to manual in my office, and disable it when i go back home.

**Already tried:**

I have already seen another [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/912351/how-to-configure-to-auto-detect-proxy) and followed this [tutorial](http://xmodulo.com/how-to-set-up-proxy-auto-config-on-ubuntu-desktop.html) and setup  `/etc/proxy.pac`  as follows:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host)
{
  if (isInNet(myIpAddress(), "172.16.15.121", "255.255.255.0"))
    {
    if (isInNet(host, "192.168.0.109", "255.255.255.0"))
      return "DIRECT";
    if (shExpMatch(url, "http:*"))
      return "PROXY 172.16.1.101:8080" ;
    if (shExpMatch(url, "https:*"))
      return "PROXY 172.16.1.101:8080" ;
    if (shExpMatch(url, "ftp:*"))
      return "PROXY 172.16.1.101:8080" ;
    return "DIRECT";
  }
    else
    {
    return "DIRECT";
  }
}
```

I cannot access internet on my work place, after setting the proxy to automatic and provide configuration url `file:///etc/proxy.pac`.

**Output of few commands that might help:**

`ifconfig`

```
enp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.16.15.121  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.16.15.255
        inet6 fe80::9ad7:34ce:f3c3:29bf  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 60:eb:69:e5:b8:7d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 18232  bytes 16794351 (16.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 47  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 14989  bytes 1918912 (1.9 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 3  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 9195  bytes 664533 (664.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 9195  bytes 664533 (664.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`hostname -i`

```
127.0.1.1
```